# How to quantify the amount of noise you add to an image

Tags: python, numpy, noise

I am looking at greyscale data that exists in a 3D volume that can be imported as a 3D numpy array with values from -1 to 1. The data was taken on an imaging system and depicts a 3D volume with higher values and background noise as random values.

To test an alignment program I am currently trying to add noise of different levels to this numpy array. My current method for this is as follows:

```
def RandomNoise():
    """Function to make a numpy array of 100x100x100 of random noise"""
    NoiseArray = np.random.normal(-0.5,0.5,size=(100,100,100))

    return NoiseArray
```

I then just alter the values -0.5 or 0.5 to change the amount of noise I create.

I then add the noise by doing:

```
Noise = RandomNoise()

Volumewithnoise = (np.clip((Volume + Noise) * (1 - Volume), -1, 1))
```

Whilst this does indeed make my image noisy I don't really know how to quantify in any way the amount of noise I am adding relative to the initial image. Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your function , in fact random.normal is a gaussian noise function and not an uniform distribution, So [-0.5, 0.5] doesn't mean the noise is between 0.5 and -0.5

You should make your function like this

```
def RandomNoise( magnitude ):
    """Function to make a numpy array of 100x100x100 of random noise"""
    NoiseArray = np.random.normal(0, magnitude ,size=(100,100,100))

    return NoiseArray
```

As you can read in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) the random normal has a mean and a standard deviation. If you want to simulate noise, the mean should be zero and the standard deviation is equivalent to the magnitude of the noise.

So this way you have a single parameter to control the amount of noise

Comment: Thank you I must have miss-understood this function. Am I right in saying this will essentially plot a bell curve at 0 y with a magnitude of 0.5? Perhaps I should just use the random uniform function.

Comment: The most common type of noise is normal (gaussian). So I think you are using the right one. However it can depend on de application. Here you can see the density function of the noise you are generating. https://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/normal.html   As you say it is a bell curve, but the magnitude is not 0.5

Comment: Thank you so much this is super useful. I assume the sigma value is essentially my magnitude here.